# move a nav bar button a little to the right

Tags: swift, xcode

I [image]have this login page and I want to be able to modify the back button. I want to move the back button to the right, I tried the CGRect command but it didnt work. How can I move this arrow to the right. Thank you.

```
var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide!
func addBackButton() {


    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        layoutGuide = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    }
    let backButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow.png"), for: .normal) // Image can be downloaded from here below link
    backButton.setTitleColor(backButton.tintColor, for: .normal) // You can change the TitleColor
    backButton.tintColor = blueColors
    backButton.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    backButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.backAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)


}
@objc func backAction(_ sender:UIButton) -> Void {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: why dont u had add to custom rightBarButtonItem instead of leftBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set your button like this:

```
func addBackButton() {
    let backButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow.png"), for: .normal)
    backButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
    backButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.backAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 30))
    view.bounds = view.bounds.offsetBy(dx: -40, dy: 0)
    view.addSubview(backButton)
    let backButtonView = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonView
}
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

To keep this button in the center:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = backButton;
```

To keep this button in the right:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
```

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific. move the button about 40 points right

Comment: Then you can try 
backButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
play around with left parameter to suit your requirement.

Comment: that just squeezes the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button on the right side, just change self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem to self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.

Otherwise, since you have nothing else in the Navigation bar, just get rid of the Navigation bar entirely and add a normal button where you want the back button to be.

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific. move the button about 40 points right

Comment: I personally would not use a button in a NAV bar and just add a UIButton to the screen. However, you can probably easily trick it by adding a couple spaces into the title of the button. Try adding backButton.setTitle("          ", for: .normal) to add spaces to the title and backButton.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft to put image on the right side

Comment: thats pretty smart. Thank you. Is there a way to move it down as well?

Comment: Not that I know of off hand. Navigation bars are not very customizable. They basically just want you to have 1 button on the left, 1 on the right, and a title or searchbar in the middle. On screens like this, I usually just add a view at the top of the view controller and add all the IBOutlets I want in storyboard. This way you can totally customize the look.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. I just have one more think. This works for two view controllers, however there is one view controller that is not forcing right to left. Do you know any reason why?

Comment: I would need to see the code for the button. Make sure you are using setImage and not setBackgroundImage. You can try the following to see if it makes it any better.....  backButton.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill ..... backButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill ..... backButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit.